# Trying to add header via css is repeating

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to place this header in the css but without luck i tried placing it in width container but its just repeating itself.

```
background:url(http://outpostmotorsports.com/OPMSwordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Y5a5qUNx6jvD9pN6AH5VMslP656QnElptjDvGKR65Fk.jpg) no-repeat;
```

**Edit to add css code**

```
.width-container, .flex-caption .slider-container {-moz-transition: all
.2s ease-in-out; -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
background:url(http://outpostmotorsports.com/OPMSwordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Y5a5qUNx6jvD9pN6AH5VMslP656QnElptjDvGKR65Fk.jpg) no-repeat;}
```

If you look at the source in css you will c width container at line 41

I trying to add the header for all pages from here

http://outpostmotorsports.com/OPMSwordpress/inventory/1989-harley-davidson-sportster/

Note 2

Its still showing it three times
[image]

Comment: check the edit i was also asking to check the live url to see why that snipet did not work

Comment: try this.(!important) `background:url(http://outpostmotorsports.com/OPMSwordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Y5a5qUNx6jvD9pN6AH5VMslP656QnElptjDvGKR65Fk.jpg) no-repeat !important`

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
 background:url(http://outpostmotorsports.com/OPMSwordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/wp_header.jpg) 
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

> The background-repeat property sets if/how a background image will be
>   repeated.
>
> By default, a background-image is repeated both vertically and
>   horizontally.
>
> Tip: The background image is placed according to the
>   background-position property. If no background-position is specified,
>   the image is always placed at the element's top left

Source: (w3schools)

Good luck!

Comment: its still doing three times ffs

Comment: maybe its not the right div as its repeated in code can you have a look at the correct div plz

Comment: did not notice you editted your post, I'll have a look.

Comment: You still use this one: background:url(http://outpostmotorsports.com/OPMSwordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Y5a5qUNx6jvD9pN6AH5VMslP656QnElptjDvGKR65Fk.jpg) no-repeat;} ? Because I pointed out that that is wrong!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this code

```
.width-container, 
.flex-caption .slider-container {
-moz-transition: all
.2s ease-in-out; 
-webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
background:url(http://outpostmotorsports.com/OPMSwordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Y5a5qUNx6jvD9pN6AH5VMslP656QnElptjDvGKR65Fk.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

then you are adding the background image to more than one element.

I'd suggest you try adding a **new** rule:

```
.width-container{
background:url(http://outpostmotorsports.com/OPMSwordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Y5a5qUNx6jvD9pN6AH5VMslP656QnElptjDvGKR65Fk.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```